# Test if input is Alphanumeric or not with JasmineJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine

My last question for today is not really a question, I would like to have your opinion about this JasmineJS test code I created to test if user entered alphanumeric or not.

I have an HTML input box called username:

```
Username: <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="input" value="testinput" />
```

I created a Javascript function to filter user input if the input is alphanumeric or not.

```
function acceptOnlyAlphanumeric() {
  var usernameInput = document.register.username.value;

  if(!/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test(usernameInput)) {
    console.log("Please enter only numbers and letters. No special character!")
    return true;
  }
    return false;
}
```

Inside my JasmineJS folder I created a service file to test the filter user input feature. My service goes like this:

```
Services = {
  userFilter : function () {
    var usernameInput = 'ThisIsAnAlphanumeric112233';

    if(!/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test(usernameInput)) {
      console.log("Please enter only numbers and letters. No special character!")
      return true;
    }
      return false;
  }
};
```

Then my jasmine script goes like this:

```
describe("Test if user enters an acceptable user input which is alphanumeric", function () {
    it("Should test if user enters alphanumeric or not", function () {
      expect(Services.userFilter()).toEqual(false);
    });
  });
```

Everythings works just fine, but I am concerned about the validity of the test. Bottom question is, is this the correct way to test the javascript function with JasmineJS? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good test, as well as good code is modular. You are just testing if your code returns false. To check if your code is correctly testing if a string is alphanumeric you would want to test it against strings that are alphanumeric as well as strings that aren't alphanumeric. I would pass the string into the function you are testing.

```
Services = {
  userFilter : function (userInput) {
  //var usernameInput = 'ThisIsAnAlphanumeric112233';
  if(!/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test(userInput)) {
    console.log("Please enter only numbers and letters. No special character!")
  return true;
  }
  return false;
  }
};




   describe("Test if user enters an acceptable user input which is alphanumeric", function () {
    it("Should test if user enters alphanumeric or not", function () {
      expect(Services.userFilter('ThisIsAnAlphanumeric112233')).toEqual(true);
    });
  });
describe("Test if user enters an acceptable user input which is alphanumeric", function () {
    it("Should test if user enters alphanumeric or not", function () {
      expect(Services.userFilter('ThisIsAnAlphanumeric#$$@@')).toEqual(false);
    });
  });
```

Comment: OMG thank you so much . . you just opened my third eye called JasmineJs . . :) my fundamental knowledge of JasmineJS is now complete. Thank you so much for the demonstration . . :) solved

Comment: so to clarify, the parameter "userInput" can be changed to any parameter name like "input", or "inputValue" . . ? :)

Comment: Yeah totally! You could set it to anything you want as long as you use is it wherever you would use the input value.

Comment: I tested it and still works after changing the parameter userInput.

Comment: Case closed :) thanks again . . this question and your answer is surely helpful to newbies :)